# What's the recommended way to store configuration data in a Windows service?

Tags: windows, go, windows-services

So, I have written a Windows service in Go using [this API](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sys/windows/svc).

Everything is working well, but I am wondering what's the best way to store configuration data in a service.

Usually, I use [SHGetKnownFolderPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/desktop/bb762188(v=vs.85).aspx) to get to the AppData directory and create my app directory in there.

However, in a service this gives me a path in C:/Windows/system32/config/userprofile, which is fine technically since I can do what I need in there, but I'm left wondering if maybe there's a preferred way to store configuration.

Is it better to use the registry for this ? Or is there something else on Windows for this purpose ?

What do Windows sysadmins expect from a service in this case ?

Thanks.

Comment: Services should pretty much NEVER use any of the SH* methods as they all, for the most part, assume an interactive user is available to answer prompts and such like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost always better off storing your configuration data in Registry. That is what a typical Windows admin would expect of a well behaved service. Windows ain't Unix. :-)

You can use [this](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sys/windows/registry) package to interact with the registry.

Comment: yeah I was looking at this package which triggered this question. Thanks!